# How do I disable a request for a user name in creating a Azure Media Services video asset using CloudMediaContext.Assets.Create

Tags: asp.net-mvc, video-processing, azure-media-services

I have created a asp.net mvc partial view which in conjunction with ajax uploads an mp4 file to Azure blob storage, acquires the resulting blob into an Azure media storage asset, encodes the asset as an adaptivebitratemp4 asset and then publishes that asset. Everything works fine on my local development web site. However when I publish that solution to my Azure development web site the solution stops working. On the local site the code request (through a popup) that I verify my Azure account username; the Azure development site does not make this request and I think the system is "hanging" on my lack of response to this request. I believe that the following  call contains the request for verification:

```
IAsset asset = _context.Assets.Create("NewAsset_" + Guid.NewGuid(), AssetCreationOptions.None);
```

Where `_context` is an instance of `CloudMediaContext`.

Two questions:

1. I vaguely remember seeing a discussion relating to this scenario but have been unable to find it? Any pointers to the topic?
2. As any user who can get to this upload view has already been validated as a legitimate user with rights to upload and create their own video, I have no need to do it here. CloudMediaContext.Assets.Create does not seem to require a username. How can I disable this request for a username?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you John. That was it. New to Media Services and made the wrong choice in setting up the account.

Answer (score 0):

How are you doing authentication to Azure Media services ?
Sounds like you used interactive user auth and not service principal for the AAD auth. Web apps should always default to using service principal auth and avoid the pop up.